# "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream" when capturing video with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, alsa, v4l2

I'm trying to capture VHS video on Linux using a new USB capture device and FFMPEG.

I'm able to successfully capture either only audio (using Alsa), or only video (using v4l2) but when I try to do both with the same command I get errors and the video comes out with really screwed up video and sound:

- Here's an example clip - https://streamable.com/oyq3t
- The full ffmpeg debug output is here: https://pastebin.com/pPN1uXg7

This is the command I'm using:

`ffmpeg -report -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 720x480 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 3584 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 -vcodec h264_omx -zerocopy 1 -b:v 1750k -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -b:a 96k -strict -2 test-combine.m4v`

This ffmpeg command works perfectly well using a different USB device very similar to this one and the exact same PC/VCR setup (I'm using a raspberry pi, h264_omx is the hardware encoder). So I'm surprised this isn't working. The main error messages see to be these, repeated:

`[aac @ 0x1017ba0] Queue input is backward in time
[ipod @ 0x1015490] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 307984, current: 307814; changing to 307985. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`

Does anyone know what could be happening here and how to get the command to work? A few things I have tried with no improvement so far:

- switching the order of the Alsa and the v4l2 parameters in the command
- Haphazardly adding a few ffmpeg arguments that I found from google searches, namely `use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -fflags +genpts  -correct_ts_overflow 0` (included all together at the front of the command - no luck)
- replacing the device itself in case it's defective (same result with the second one)

Thanks!

Comment: When you capture only audio, do the `Non-monotonous DTS` messages still appear?

Comment: Just checked again - nope, I do not get those messages with audio only

Comment: I also came across the `-debug_ts` parameter - I am still trying to understand what the output from it means but it looks to me like the timestamps for the audio and video tracks are way far apart from each other https://pastebin.com/hbZsqaFP